# How to add an operator function to a primative data type c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators, primitive-types

So what I am trying to do is add an operator to a primitive data type that would work as follows.

```
int m_number = 10;
m_number.CheckCondition (1,10);
```

with the function CheckCondition working like so

```
public bool CheckCondition (<The m_number variable>,int t_lower,int t_upper);
```

Now I might be mistaken in this but I think I remember seeing a way of doing this but can no longer find it where the param: (The m_number variable) is something like

```
this <Word I Forgot> m_number
```

as the first param.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what I have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You can create it like that

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this int i, int lower, int upper)
    {
        return lower < i && upper > i;
    }
}
```

and then use it on any `int`:

```
bool check = 1.IsBetween(0, 10);
```

---

Note that since `int` is a *value* type, you cannot change it (like in `i.ChangeSign()` to change the actual value of `i`). You can only *return* a changed value if you need that.